# Verify .mat file exists and is not Corrupt - Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, concurrency, mat-file

I have 2 independent Matlab workers, with FIRST getting/saving data and SECOND reading it (and doing some calculations etc).

FIRST saves data as .mat file on the hard-disk while SECOND reads it from there.  It takes ~20 seconds to `SAVE` this data as .mat and 8millisec to `DELETE` it. Before SAVING data, FIRST deletes the old file and then saves a newer version.

How can the SECOND verify that data exists and `is not corrupt`?  I can use `exists` but that doesn't tell me if the data is corrupt or not. For eg, if SECOND tries to read data exactly when FIRST is saving it, `exists` passes but `LOAD` gives you an error saying - Data Corrupt etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Parallel Computing Toolbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, without some synchronization mechanism - by the time SECOND completes its check and starts to read the file, FIRST might have started writing it again. You need some sort of lock or mutex.

Two options for base Matlab.

If this is on a local filesystem, you could use a separate lock file sitting next to the data file to manage concurrent access to the data file. Use Java's NIO FileChannel and FileLock objects from within Matlab to lock the first byte of the lock file and use that as a semaphore to control access to the data file, so the reader waits until the writer is finished and vice versa. (If this is on a network filesystem, don't try this - file locking may seem to work but usually is not officially supported and in my experience is unreliable.)

Or you could just put a try/catch around your `load()` call and have it pause a few seconds and retry if you get a corrupt file error. The .mat file format is such that you won't get a partial read if the writer is still writing it; you'll get that corrupt file error. So you could use this as a lazy sort of collision detection and backoff. This is what I usually do.

To reduce the window of contention, consider having FIRST write to a temporary file in the same directory, and then use a rename to move it to its final destination. That way the file is only unavailable during a quick filesystem move operation, not the 20 seconds of data writing. If you have multiple writers, stick the PID and hostname in the temp file name to avoid collisions.

Comment: Thanks! Suggestion# 2 and 3 are both helpful.  Just managed to rename a file using matlab `dos` operator.

Comment: you can rename files from within matlab using the `movefile` command. There's no need to use DOS, which would make your code platform-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic resource sharing problem between 2 threads (R-W)

In short, you should find a method of inter-workers safe communication.  Check [this out](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/f1-6010.html#f1-7418).

Also, try to type

> showdemo('paralleldemo_communic_prof')

in Matlab